# Global preferences for AppleScript app

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to save some kind of settings for an app create in AppleScript?

The settings should be loaded at the beginning of the script and be saved at the end of the script.

Example:

```
if loadSetting("timesRun") then
    set timesRun to loadSetting("timesRun")
else
    set timesRun to 0
end if
set timesRun to timesRun + 1
display dialog timesRun
saveSetting("timesRun", timesRun)
```

Where the dialog would show 1 the first time running the script, 2 the second time...

And the functions loadSetting and saveSetting would be the functions i need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH223-SW2) are persistent, though the saved value is overwritten by the value specified in the script whenever you re-save the script. Run:

```
property |count| : 0
display alert "Count is " & |count|
set |count| to |count| + 1
```

a few times, re-save it then run it a few more.

If you want to use the user defaults system, you can use `do shell script "defaults ..."` commands or (if using Applescript Studio) `default entry "propertyName" of user defaults`. In Applescript Studio, you [bind values to user defaults](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/cocoabindings.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is also working well (check the first comment to the hint):

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050402194557539

It uses the "defaults" system and you get your preferences in the ~/Library/Preferences

Answer (score 3):

Applescript supports natively reading and writing plists through System Events:

```
use application "System Events" # Avoids tell blocks, note: 10.9 only

property _myPlist : "~/Library/Preferences/com.plistname.plist

set plistItemValue to get value of property list item "plistItem" of contents of property list file _myPlist
set plistItemValue to plistItemValue + 1

set value of property list item "plistItem" of contents of property list file _myPlist to plistItemValue
```

The only problem with this is that it can't create the plists so if the existence of the plist is not certain you need to wrap it on a **try**.

```
try 
    set plistItemValue to get value of property list item "plistItem" of contents of property list file _myPlist
on error -1728 # file not found error
    do shell script "defaults write com.plistname.plist plistItem 0"
    set plistItemValue to get value of property list item "plistItem" of contents of property list file _myPlist
end try
```